How can I safely move saltwater snails between tanks?
I want to move one of my saltwater snails into a different aquarium. I usually just pick them up and move them into the next tank. However, a friend told me that I should be much more careful in transferring snails.
Is there a generalized safety procedure for moving snails? Should I move them into a cup and slowly add water from the new tank? Should I float them in the new tank first? What is the safest practice here?
The new tank they are moving to is heated to the same temperature as their old tank.
